# Normalizing pandas DataFrame with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I need to normalize data by level 1 in multi-index, given

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3), index=[["a","a","b","b"],[1,2,1,2]],
                  columns=["x","y","z"])
```

so that `df` is

```
     x   y   z
a 1  0   1   2
  2  3   4   5
b 1  6   7   8
  2  9  10  11
```

I need to normalize every column by the 1st level of index, to get

```
     x       y      z
a 1  0      1/5    2/7
  2  1      4/5    5/7
b 1  6/15   7/17   8/19
  2  9/15  10/17  11/19
```

(although, obviously, with floats instead of ratios)

I suppose I could do something by iterating over columns and values of the 1st level of multi-index, but I am sure there is a one-liner...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is with a groupby:

```py
df/df.groupby(level=0).transform('sum')
Out[87]: 
       x         y         z
a 1  0.0  0.200000  0.285714
  2  1.0  0.800000  0.714286
b 1  0.4  0.411765  0.421053
  2  0.6  0.588235  0.578947
```